# Im trying to search and download a file from Azure blob storage and im thrown with error

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Below is my query:

found_files = []

```
for blob in blob_list:
    if search_query.lower() in blob.name.lower():
        found_files.append(blob.name)
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
        try:
            blob_data = download_blob_with_retry(blob_client)
            with open(f"{local_download_path}/{blob.name}", "wb") as f:
                f.write(blob_data)
        except ResourceNotFoundError as ex:
            print(f"Blob not found: {ex}")
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Error downloading blob: {ex}")
```

IM thrown with error:

Unable to stream download: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I uploaded a folder with three files as a blob to my storage account container as below,

[image]

***I made some changes to your code and can able to download a blob from my storage account container.***

**Code:**

```
import os
import time
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError

connection_string = "<connec_string>"
container_name = "<container_name>"
local_download_path = "<path/to/save the downloaded file>"
search_query = "<storage_blob_name>"

def download_blob_with_retry(blob_client, max_retries=5, retry_delay=2):
    for retry_count in range(max_retries):
        try:
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
            return blob_data
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"Error downloading blob: {ex}")
            print(f"Retrying ({retry_count + 1}/{max_retries})...")
            time.sleep(retry_delay)

    print("Failed to download blob after multiple retries.")
    return None

try:
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()

    found_files = []

    for blob in blob_list:
        if search_query.lower() in blob.name.lower():
            found_files.append(blob.name)
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
            try:
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(local_download_path, blob.name)), exist_ok=True)
                
                blob_data = download_blob_with_retry(blob_client)
                if blob_data is not None:
                    with open(os.path.join(local_download_path, blob.name), "wb") as f:
                        f.write(blob_data)
                    print(f"Blob downloaded successfully: {blob.name}")
            except ResourceNotFoundError as ex:
                print(f"Blob not found: {ex}")
            except Exception as ex:
                print(f"Error downloading blob: {ex}")

except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Error connecting to Azure Blob Storage: {ex}")
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

***And downloads the blobs in a folder from the storage account container to the given path as below***,

[image]

Comment: Im still thrown with the same error, when I had used your code

Comment: @AshwinRoy Can you check the account details provided in the code from Azure Portal like connection_string, container etc?

Comment: @AshwinRoy Check your internet connection once. Ensure that your internet connection is stable and working properly. Try opening other websites or streaming services to see if the issue is specific to the website or service you are trying to access.

Comment: The above code only works if the file is present directly inside the blob. If there are numerous folders within kamcontainer and your file is present in the path kamstore-> kamcontainer-> image ->  samplekam.txt

you will be thrown with the error 

Unable to stream download: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))

Comment: @AshwinRoy I edited my answer, can you check it once

Comment: It works only if the container has less number of files in it. Say if you have 5 lakh + files in your container in the same path, this exception is thrown.

I need something that works with large data